# foreach after Linq query on a datatable not working

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a LINQ query in C# which runs on a datatable that is generated from a SQL Server exectution:

```
DataTable dtSubjects = db.ExecuteDataTable();
            var subjectsWithoutParent = from row in dtSubjects.AsEnumerable() 
                                        where row["ParentID"] != DBNull.Value && row.Field<int>("ParentID") == 0 
                                        select row;
```

Afterwards, there's a foreach that should run on each DataRow returned from the the LINQ. However, the foeach code does not run.

```
foreach (DataRow rowSubject in subjectsWithoutParent)
            {
                rowSubject["ParentID"] = DBNull.Value;
            }
```

The Datatable has rows on it, and as far as I can tell subjectsWithoutParent gets at least one row from the LINQ.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does 'not run' mean? ... does it not compile, do you get an exception ...?? are you sure that the sequence `subjectsWithoutParent`  contains any items? **and**, "and as far as I can tell subjectsWithoutParent gets at least one row from the LINQ" - just use `.Any()` to validate this!

Comment: I should clarify that. The code compiles, but the compiler thinks there are no rows in subjectsWithoutParent , as it doesn't "get into" the foreach, or however you call a loop which does not run

Comment: i don't think that the **compiler** (sic) has no clue about the items in the sequence ... just do a `.Any()`-call to clarify that!

Comment: what happens if you use .ToList() extension method? Also, when you debug after LINQ query, do you see elements in `subjectsWithoutParent`?

Comment: @jbkkd: How have you checked it? What does `subjectsWithoutParent.Count()` return?

Comment: is ti working for you ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> subjectsWithoutParent = (from row in 
dtSubjects.AsEnumerable()                                          
where row["ParentID"] != DBNull.Value && 
row.Field<int>("ParentID") == 0                                          
select row).ToList<DataRow>();
```

and then check `subjectsWithoutParent.Any()` is it retrieving data or not?

Comment: .... do not use `Count()` ... if the result of `.AsEnumerable()` is not of type `ICollection`, the enumerator is going to get executed and travels all the way to the last element to get the correct amount - rather use `.Any()`!

Comment: This helped me very much to understand I have a problem with the SQL query that executes before the LINQ, and therefore the LINQ Query wasn't the problem. Still, I'm marking this as the answer for helping me discover the real problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the filter criteria is not removing all rows (this would be the case if all rows had a non-null and non-zero ParentID value)? You can test this out by commenting out the `where` line in the Linq query and the `rowSubject` update line in the foreach. Then hit it with the debugger.